# Limit user views to infopath files created within Share Point 2007

Tags: file, permissions, view, creation

I am a new admin for our SharePoint 2007 site. I've searched for and found many similar questions but none quite like what I'm trying to achieve. 
So here's the rundown.
I've created an Infopath form that everyone has to fill out. IT's an emergency contact form. The tricky part is that I don't want anyone to see anyone elses form that is submitted. The managers are allowed to see them all. I've limited the view for users to view only what they create, but they can easily change the view to see them all. 
We have too many people, and too many groups to limit everyone. I work for a large company.

Any ideas how to approach this? IS there a way to have the creation of the form on one page and the storing/submission of the form to save in another location(with limited access to that particular site)?

I'm open to all ideas here, as I said, I'm new to this and am trying to learn as fast as I can.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. The fix was actually in the InfoPath form itself, not SharePoint. I just had to change the destination on the submit properties to a secured location.

Sort of embarrassed I didn't figure that one out a lot sooner. :/

Thanks